Add app launcher icons on top bar
I'm using gnome classic on Ubuntu 24.04, and I would like to add some launcher icons on the top bar, but I can't find how. In previous versions of Ubuntu/Linux/Gnome, I would either right-click where I wanted the icon and a menu would pop up with the option "add app launcher", or I would find the app in the menu and drag the icon where I want it on the bar, but none of the options is available in my version.
I don't know what version of gnome classic I'm using, I did echo "$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP", and "echo $DESKTOP_SESSION", and all it says is it's gnome-classic, which I already knew, but no version number is given. If the exact version number is needed, let me know how to retrieve it.
Here is where I want the icons.


The top bar is a gnome extension. I have four: -
gnome-extensions list

ding@rastersoft.com
tiling-assistant@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com

The top bar is the third one down ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
In the old days all the standard applications had applets associated with them that was displayed by the top bar. These have now been removed although third party an some other legacy ones still use them. I use ClassicMenuIndicator which still uses one. I believe that Dropbox still uses one too.
You can customise the top panel a little using the following GUI tool: -
extension-manager


The following link does give some extensions that do offer some extra features that can be explored.
https://itsfoss.com/customize-gnome-top-panel/

The following link also has some interesting apps to extend the top bar.
https://linux.how2shout.com/4-extensions-to-change-top-bar-in-ubuntu-24-04/
I quite like the look of Dash to panel. An icon taskbar for the Gnome Shell. This extension moves the dash into the gnome main panel so that the application launchers and system tray are combined into a single panel, similar to that found in KDE Plasma and Windows 7+. A separate dock is no longer needed for easy access to running your favorite applications. (I haven't tried it though.)
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/
